# excel using 2 lookup columns in vlookup

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

Basic scenario is I want to use column A2 or B2 to vlookup to a different sheet.  A2 and B2 can be different strings, but if either of those match I want to bring in the value from sheet I am looking up to.

The formula below works well if I only care about A2, but the other sheet can have a value that matches either A2 or B2.

Any thoughts on how to modify the formula below so it brings in the lookup value that matches?

```
=IF('Car Accounts'!A4  ="","",VLOOKUP('Car Accounts'!A4,DCTM!B:B,1,0))
```

In lamen's terms something like this:

```
=IF('Car Accounts'!A4  ="","",VLOOKUP('Car Accounts'!**A4 OR B4**,DCTM!B:B,1,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

use IFFEROR:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP('Car Accounts'!A4,DCTM!B:B,1,0),VLOOKUP('Car Accounts'!B4,DCTM!B:B,1,0))
```

Comment: Thanks this definitely works just wondering, if I wanted to just make the result be blank if A4 is blank, do you know how to work that in?  I Tried putting an if statement around the iferror but it fails:  Currently what happens is it runs and displays error when there's not data to lookup with   In other words if i put if (expression above, "","") it doesn't do what I would expect it to

Comment: `=IF('Car Accounts'!A4  ="","",IFERROR(VLOOKUP('Car Accounts'!A4,DCTM!B:B,1,0),VLOOKUP('Car Accounts'!B4,DCTM!B:B,1,0)))`